# Use Maven to customize and build another Maven project

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

What I want to achieve is the following:

- Checkout external project from svn
- Replace spring.xml with my customized version
- Change version of a dependency
- Build
- Package

Are there standard maven plugins to handle all these goals?

Answer (score 2):

For svn operations, you can use: org.tmatesoft.svnkit:svnkit

For replacing spring.xml with a customized version: maven-assembly-plugin, maven-resources-plugin would both work, depending on what exactly you need to do (I'm assuming there's more work here).

For building and packaging, you can use the maven-invoker-plugin.  That plugin basically lets you point at a project and run "mvn clean package" or whatever other maven commands you want such as invoking a plugin.  It's pretty much just a way to run maven from maven.